# Does Pagination using spring data JPA takes care of clearing session cache?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, out-of-memory

I am using spring data JPA for retrieving a large dataset from my DB table. I just wanted to know, does pagination with Spring data JPA takes care of clearing this large dataset from hibernate sessions(first level cache)?
So that I will not end up with out of memory exception.

```
    public List<FoodCategoryDTO> retrieveAllFoodCategories(int pageNum){
        List<FoodCategoryDTO> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        foodCategoryRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNum, 10)).forEach(category -> {
            FoodCategoryDTO foodCategory = new FoodCategoryDTO();
            foodCategory.setCategoryId(category.getCategoryId());
            foodCategory.setCategoryName(category.getCategoryName());
            foodCategory.setActive(category.isActive());
            foodCategory.setCaterable(category.isCaterable());
            foodCategory.setDescription(category.getDescription());
            categories.add(foodCategory);
        });

        return categories;
    }
```

Comment: That depends on whether you're paginating in a new transaction (and thus most likely a new Hibernate session) or not. The first level cache is bound to the Hibernate session and thus will automatically get cleared once that session ends. The Hibernate session normally is bound to the transaction so if the transaction ends the session ends as well. Pagination and other queries won't cause the first level cache to be cleared though.

Comment: You can always get an out of memory error, if you load more data into memory than you have. But the problem is not the database cache.